# How do you test methods as you are coding?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0

Currently using VS2010 Ultimate. In a prior version of VS there was a utility that you could use to test methods while you were coding (Some sort of test bench, I think). The benefit of this, was in the case of a large web app, you didn't need to spin up and wait for the entire application to be ready before testing your method.

What sorts of tests / jigs do you use to test static and instance methods in your apps w/o firing up the entire application?

Comment: Do you mean Unit tests ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the MSTest Project and have it reference your app you are trying to test.

Comment: I also agree with scottm, LinqPad works wonders I use it everyday.

Answer (score 3):

[LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) works great for running small bits of code.

Answer (score 1):

VS2010 comes with a system that allow you made unit tests... and let you run each tests individually if you want. You may be interested in this channel9 video about unit testing with vs2010: http://channel9.msdn.com/blogs/visualstudio/test-driven-development-with-visual-studio-2010

Answer (score 0):

I think the question here is how to start your method from anywhere, to have an entry point to quickly test something.

If I remember correctly, [TestDriven.Net](http://www.testdriven.net/) allowed you to do this.